# What is expressed by the question, "Y qué tal lo llevas"?

Tags: vocabulario

I'm enjoying a [Spanish listening lesson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h81fqZPHqDg) on Youtube. It is of a conversation between two people. There is this one part of the conversation I fail to understand.

What is being expressed by the question below in bold font:

> Person1: Porque mañana tengo un examen.
>
> Person2: **¿Y qué tal lo llevas?**

Comment: By the way, "_qué tal lo llevas_" is an idiom, and I can't tell you where it is used. In my country Chile, that phrase is not understood in any context, because it does not correspond to any of the meanings of the verb "_llevar_" that we normally use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a little bit more of the conversation can give more context:

> Person1: Porque mañana tengo un examen.
>
> Person2: ¿Y qué tal lo llevas?
>
> Person1: Regular.
>
> Person2: ¿No has estudiado suficiente?

In this case with *¿Y qué tal lo llevas?* Person2 is asking Person1 how he/she is feeling about having an exam tomorrow. With the answer "Regular" (so-so), Person1 says the situation is not that good.

A translation of *¿qué tal lo llevas?* could then be: How is it going?

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. But now I feel like a lazy person - all I had to do was go to SpanishDict.com and scroll down a bit, to see the definition: ¿cómo lo llevas? how are you getting on?

Comment: Exactly. I think that would be the best translation so far read here.